# GROUP BY: shorthand

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I have a query (here shorter):

```
SELECT 
a,b,c 
,SUM(something) as s
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Let's say I have 23 cols before the `SUM`

Is there a shorthand that would save me the hassle of writing `1,2,3` all down to `23`?

Comment: No - in fact many SQL systems don't even let you use the column number in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Yepp. Although, on teradata column ordinals still  work. Anyhow, having to write 23 aliases it is even more time consuming than writing a seq of column ordinals (which I can generate with a script rather easily)

Comment: My point is, having to type 1-23 seems a LOT better than having to type out aliases, so I don't see that as a huge hassle :)

Comment: Can I type `1-23`? Is it a SQL short-hand or just yours to make your point in the comment?

Comment: Generally it's easiest to copy the fields from the SELECT clause, edit out any field aliases, and change the order as needed.  This has the added advantage of not completely borking your query if you change the field order.  I only use ordinals in the ORDER BY clause anymore because I've been bitten by this.

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis lol no, that's was just my notation.  I think the best you can do is 1, 2, 3, ... , 23 (and the ellipses are my shorthand as well :) ).

Comment: @DStanley: lol. ok. too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 a,b,c 
 ,SUM(something) OVER(partition by a,b,c) as s
FROM table
```

Comment: Not sure this will work as you are not specifying a partition in the OVER part of the window SUM clause. Therefore I expect that the total sum for the entire ‘something’ column would be assigned to *every* row.

Comment: True that, I fixed it in the answer by adding the columns in partitioning clause.

Comment: How is this shorter than `group by 1,2,3,...`? Additionally it consumes way more resources.

Comment: It avoids a `GROUP BY`, that is what the original question was asking. Admittedly it is worse than the expected aggregate operation.